# Fetching countries data through XMLHTTPRequest using the countries API gettting [object object]error

Tags: javascript, json, object, xmlhttprequest

Fetching the data through this API https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/portugal. For couple of fields i.e flag,name,currency getting [object object]

```
XMLHTTPRequest

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Here we need URL for AJAX calls
//request is an object
// Type of Request - GET
request.open('GET','https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/portugal');
// open the request
//we have to send this request to the url to fetch the data
request.send();

//We need request call back on the load. callback function
request.addEventListener('load',function() {

// converting json file to normal text.

const [data] = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
console.log(data);

const html=`
<article class="country">
<img class="country__img" src="${data.flags}"/>
console.log(data.flags);
<div class="country__data">
  <h3 class="country__name">${data.name}</h3>
  <h4 class="country__region">${data.region}</h4>
  <p class="country__row"><span></span>${data.population}</p>
  <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${data.languages}</p>
  <p class="country__row"><span></span>${data.currencies}</p>
</div>
</article>
`;
```

For Flag image getting Cannot GET /[object%20Object]
other fields too [object%20Object].

Do i have to use JSON.stringify?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Ajeet

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this:

```
const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
console.log(data);
console.log(data[0].population); etc
```

ie remove the square brackets from const [data] and get using index 0

Answer (score 0):

The `data.flags` property you are using for `src` attribute is an object itself, not a simple URL, since it contains URLs for `png` and `svg` formats.

Try to pass `data.flags.png` or  `data.flags.svg` for the `src` attribute and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper notation to get values out from JSON. You can refer below code to get more understandings.

```
request.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // converting json file to normal text.
    
    const [data] = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(data);
    
    const lang = Object.values(data.languages).join(',');
    const currencies = Object.values(data.currencies).map((c) => c.name).join(',');
    
    const html = `
    <article class="country">
    <img class="country__img" src="${data.flags.png}"/>
    <div class="country__data">
        <h3 class="country__name">${data.name.common}</h3>
        <h4 class="country__region">${data.region}</h4>
        <p class="country__row"><span></span>${data.population}</p>
        <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${lang}</p>
        <p class="country__row"><span></span>${currencies}</p>
    </div>
    </article>
    `;
    const divEl = document.createElement('div');
    divEl.innerHTML = html;
    
    document.body.appendChild(divEl);
    console.log(html);
});
```